# Assigning value to variables in class from outside of class

Tags: c++

I was having trouble trying assign variables declared in a class value outside of the class in functions. Example below:

```
class player {
public:
string playerWeapon;
void setWeapon();
}
```

Then maybe outside the header file where this is declared in the cpp file:

```
void player::setWeapon(){
player playerobj;
int playerWeaponInt;
cout << "choose Number" << endl
     << "'1' for gun" << endl
     << "'2' for axe" << endl;
     cin >> playerWeaponInt;
```

Then I tried an if statement to assign the  number to a string that can be put into the variable:

```
if(playerWeaponInt == 1){

playerobj.playerWeapon = "gun";

else if (playerWeaponInt == 2){

playerobj.playerWeapon = "axe"
}
```

But hwenever i try to display it later in the program the variable is empty and nothing is display. Can anyone help me out

EDIT: Here is an extra piece of code so it will compile

```
player playerObj;
main(){
playerObj.setWeapon; 
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Please read up about encapsulation

Comment: @NathanOliver This is that example and this is not my code jsut an example i quickly wrote for this question

Comment: Perhaps spend a little more time formulating the question

Comment: How can we tell you what is wrong with your code if we don't see the code that is actually causing the problem?  We could guess and tell you to check this and that but that is not how Stack Overflow works.  You ask a concrete question and you (hopefully) get concrete answer(s)

Comment: Is anything unclear?

Comment: @Spartan5434, and not even I wrote this post myself...

Comment: @NathanOliver This is the code that is causing me issues though since the value in the class is still not displaying correctly

Comment: @SmitYcyken What?

Comment: @Spartan5434 No, it is not a complete example. Write a small example that we can compile ourselves.

Comment: @matli Just updated

Comment: @Spartan5434: The code clearly shows what is the problem. Unfortunately someone powerful enough here on SO likes to be annoying for no evident (for me) reason. As the community grows is unavoidable that someone will misuse power that in a perfect world s/he shouldn't have... do not assume that because someone has an high-enough rep then for sure is smart or well behaving. It would be the same mistake as assuming that because someone is wearing a uniform then it will always be good and do well. Real world doesn't work this way.

Comment: @6502 Yeah this website just likes to flip-flop all the time. I post too much code ppl get pissed. I post a small example like they told me then they want more. Honestly, I'm done, people here think they are geniuses and critique every little thing u do in a post.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the first code line inside `setWeapon`:

```
player playerobj;
```

that will create **another player object**. Apparently instead you want to set the current weapon of the current player, the code should be:

```
void player::setWeapon(){
    cout << "choose Number" << endl
         << "'1' for gun" << endl
         << "'2' for axe" << endl;
    cin >> playerWeaponInt;
    if(playerWeaponInt == 1){
        playerWeapon = "gun"; // NOTE: no "playerobj."
    } else if (playerWeaponInt == 2){
        playerWeapon = "axe";
    }
}
```

when a method is executed there is an implicit object pointed by `this`.
When you say `playerWeapon` in a method it's intended that you mean
`this->playerWeapon`.

Comment: And to be clear, that's the `player playerobj`in the setWeapon method that should be removed. Otherwise you create a temporary player object which just exists within that method.

Comment: @matli: indeed, after rewording is more clear

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't expose the internal represenatation of your `class player` by making it's internal data `playerWeapon`. Better make a method to set and make the data private. Proposal:

```
class player {
public:
    void setPlayerWeapon(const string &playerWeapon);
    void setWeapon();
private:
    string playerWeapon;
}
```

Next, where do you want to display the content of playerobj.playerWeapon? As `player::setWeapon` has ist own object `playerobj` which will be destructed when leaving the method you can only display it inside the current method call. Probably this is not what you wanted to do. I assume you wanted to set `playerWeapon` of your current object. If so, just remove the auxillary object 
`player playerobj`from the method and assign the weapon string directly to the objects member variable.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to print it in another class method outside of the class

Comment: @Spartan5434 So please remove the local `playerobj` from `setWeapon`. Add an accessor method `string getPlayerWeapon() const { return playerWeapon; }` to your class to get access outside of the `player` class..